# Debugging Com-Visible DLL for VB6 App

Tags: .net, dll, vb6, vb6-migration, comvisible

I'm updating an app that was written in VB6. I want to write the New code in VS2010 and keep it in a DLL. But I cannot figure out how to Debug the DLL code. I can get it to step into the DLL code from a test app in VS2010, but not from the real app in VB6. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running the APP in the VB6 IDE attach the Visual Studio 2010 debugger to the VB6.Exe (Tools -> Attach To Process in VS2010) and select the correct level of Managed Code you are using (DotNet 4.0 or DotNet 2.0 depending on what your DLL was written in).  You should have your DotNet Dll project loaded already in Visual Studio 2010, and then you can set break points in your Visual Studio 2010 project.[image: Attach to process]

Comment: +1. For completeness: you can also attach to a built exe rather than the VB6 IDE itself. If you do this, it is a good idea to build the exe with debug symbols turned on (create a PDB file)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the clear cut tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730840%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#dbughybvb6_topic3)
. I've tried this working good